# jQuery scrollbar plugin: multiple styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I use the jQuery scrollbar plugin:
https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar

My scrollbar is working. I changed the colors in the css file and this is also working. The problem is I want to use this scrollbar twice on my web page.

But for the second use I need different styles (other colors for the bar and background). But I only have one CSS-file.
How would you solve this problem?

Comment: u can add some classes to scroll parent and add style for custom classes

Answer (score 0):

You can add some additional classes to elements, then add custom style in the end of css file, isn`t it? Or I miss something?

You have only one css file or you have access only to css file and nothing else? I can`t actually understand what is the point?

Comment: The problem was the scrollbar DOM elements are added by the plugin. I uncommented the parts of the css file that are about the colors. Then I use these uncommented expression and put a .class1 in front of it and for the other use a .class2. That way it worked.